# how to keep random sample result the same each time running callback or running server?

Tags: plotly-dash

In my callback, there is a function. Within that function, I need to use `random.sample(list, 10)` to draw 10 samples each time inside a loop. So, I use `random.seed(400)` inside the function before the loop of `random.sample(list, 10)`.

Each time, when running callback, the samples are not the same. I'm not sure how to make random samples the same. Thanks

```py
def find_best(df,N_calculation):

    random.seed(400)
    
    for n_cal in tnrange(N_calculation):
        RISKY_ASSETS = random.sample(stock_list_portfolio, n_assets)
```

in callback

```py
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("portfolio-graph", "figure"),
    ],
    [
        Input('run-portfolio','n_clicks')
    ],
    [
        State('portfolio-data-year-num-slider','value'), 
        State('portfolio-opt-calc-log-num-slider','value'),  
    ],
              
    prevent_initial_call=True,   # disable output in the first load
)

 
def change_portfolio(n_clicks,delta_year,n_calculation_log):    
    
    RISKY_ASSETS_BEST= find_best(df,N_calculation)
```

Comment: In a concurrent environment, try using a `random.Random` object.

Comment: How does `change_portfolio()` (&`find_best()`) relate to the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described should work, unless the input `stock_list_portfolio` to the `random.sample()` is different each time you call it. Here is an example where it works and will print the deterministic set of elements from a list using `sample` and `seed`:

```py
import random

import dash
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div([html.P(id="paragraph_id", children=["Button not clicked"])]),
        html.Button(id="button_id", children="Run smapler"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    [Output("paragraph_id", "children")],
    [Input("button_id", "n_clicks")],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def callback(_):
    random.seed(4)
    res_list = ""
    df= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    for n_cal in range(4):
        RISKY_ASSETS = random.sample(df, n_cal)
        res_list += f"{RISKY_ASSETS}"
    return [res_list]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```